# Matlab optimproblem: Possible to use 3rd party ILP solver?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, solver, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I've been browsing the Matlab's [mixed] integer linear program ([M]ILP) commands/classes documentation to see if there is a way to define an "optimization problem" ([`optimproblem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimproblem.html)) and call out to an external [M]ILP solver using an API rather than using the native [`intlinprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html).  I haven't yet found any indication that this is possible, short of converting the problem to matrix/solver-based format ([`prob2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationproblem.prob2struct.html)) and creating my own intermediate ILP data file.  That would be beyond what I am willing to do.

Is there in fact no way to directly invoke a 3rd party solver?

If there is a way, can someone please direct me to the proper documentation page?

If there is in fact no way, can someone please confirm this?

Thanks.

**Clarification: Question emphasizes use of `optimproblem`**

I appreciate the answers and comments to date, but I realize from them that I need to emphasize a key point in the question. My aim is to exploit the high level problem specification of [`optimproblem`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimproblem.html), which uses Matlab's array syntax to compactly represent a large number of constraints, lengthy inner products for them, and for the objective function.  This is the so-called [problem-based](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-basics-problem-based.html) approach, which is akin in high level to [AMPL](http://ampl.com/BOOK/CHAPTERS/04-tut1.pdf).

In contrast, my impression from initial browsings of the cited documents on 3rd party solvers is that their inputs are at a lower level of abstraction.  This is the so-called [solver-based](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/mixed-integer-linear-programming-basics.html) approach, which colleagues have also called the "matrix level", for the following reason: The archetypal arrays x, Aeq, beq, Aineq, bineq, etc., are assumed to have been composed, and it is up to the analyst to keep track of which elements in x correspond to which (more) real-world parameters, i.e., those in the problem-based approach.

I was hoping that there was a way to use `optimproblem` and have it use a 3rd party solver so that I don't have to deal with the matrix level.  An example of the latter would be using [`prob2struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationproblem.prob2struct.html) to generate arrays to explicitly pass to external solvers via Matlab APIs (if they have them).  I want to avoid this because I don't want to keep track of which problem-based variables map to which solver-based variables, especially since the former is often of high dimensionality. Granted, [`varindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationproblem.varindex.html) simplifies the bookkeeping, but not having to code for such bookkeeping is much preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to TMW, the answer is "no" at present (May 30, 2019).

Answer (score 1):

Setup your problem using Problem Based Approach. Use prob2struct and solve using an external solver. Convert the solution back as you would have had with Problem Based Approach through mapSolution function.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optim.problemdef.optimizationproblem.mapsolution.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The opening paragraph seems to summarize the idea.  The mapSolution function should fill the need described in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- various 3rd-party optimization solvers have MATLAB APIs. For example, [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/gscplexmatlab.pdf) and [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/quickstart_mac/matlab_interface.html) both have MATLAB APIs. But you invoke them through their own function calls, not through `intlinprog`.

Comment: CPLEX actually has both, a class API and a toolbox function API. The toolbox function API was designed to resemble the matlab functions like `intlinprog` as close as possible. See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/files.html

Comment: Thanks, this is informative.  However, I need clarify that the question is how to have `optimproblem` use a 3rd party solver rather than directly invoking the 3rd party solver using its own API.  The latter seems to expect the archetypal arguments to be already assembled, i.e., x, Aeq, Beq, Aneq, Bneq, etc.  I added this elaboration to the question.  Would the answer still be "yes"? Is there another way to avoid having to directly handle said archetypal variables?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. In that case, is something like [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/) a workable solution for you? It takes a problem-based approach and calculates the solver-level matrices and vectors for you, and it can call a number of 3rd-party solvers.

Comment: Thanks, Larry. YALMIP example code looks closer to the matrix level than problem/AMPL level, and it's couched in control theory context, which can be a barrier to those from outside. The AMPL API is good for me to be aware of, as I am still getting to know the subject area and tools ecosystem. Would you agree that the answer to my question is "No, you can't have an `optimproblem` object invoke an external solver, but alternatives for defining the problem at a high level and invoking external solvers include YALMIP and the AMPL API"?

Comment: I don't know enough about `optimproblem` to say either way, so I wouldn't want to agree to that statement.